# Is there someone who is using cocos2d 0.99.5 beta3?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Definitely, I'm a newbie on 'cocos2d for iOS', and in trouble with importing the "CCTouchDispatcher.h".
Cocos2d for iphone version 0.99.4 or below, I've seen CCTouchDispatcher class successful,
but does not occur importing.
Importing works, but I cannot use CCTouchDispatcher.

Warning shows just "may not respond to..", and there's no even coloring in purple.
I hope so who solved this failure..

My preference below

OS X ver: 10.6.4

Xcode ver: 3.2.4

cocos2d for iOS: 0.99.5 beta3

Comment: I solved this moronic question by myself, just add #import <UIKit/UIKit.h> to my custom.h, it worked. But still can't use auto-completion. I don't know about that yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using cocos2d 0.99.5 beta 3 and the CCTouchDispatcher with auto complete.

In my header i import the .h file

```
#import "CCTouchDispatcher.h"
```

Then in my init method I'm doing this:

```
[[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self
                                                 priority:0
                                          swallowsTouches:FALSE];
```

This works as expected after implementing the CCTouchMoved etc methods. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah, as self commented, I imported "CCTouchDispatcher.h"! But there was nothing happened. So I added <UIKit/UIKit.h>, then it worked! But it's still no coloring. Conclusionly, I solved just "CCTouchDispatcher problem", and couldn't figure out what's wrong. Anyway, thanks for pleasure answer.

Comment: Sorry, i missed your comment. Comments on this site are so small =/